# vsftpd-cannot read config file even when file exists

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 and I just installed `vsftpd`. 
When I run the command `service vsftpd status`, I get the following output:

```
vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor   preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-10-09 19:18:50 IST;  3min 11s ago
Process: 2981 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)
Process: 2979 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 2981 (code=exited, status=2)

Oct 09 19:18:50 harshal-Lenovo-B40-70 systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP  server...
Oct 09 19:18:50 harshal-Lenovo-B40-70 systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 09 19:18:50 harshal-Lenovo-B40-70 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Oct 09 19:18:50 harshal-Lenovo-B40-70 systemd[1]: Unit vsftpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 09 19:18:50 harshal-Lenovo-B40-70 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service failed.
```

I checked `/etc/vsftpd.conf`, it exists and I did not find anything wrong in it. How can I solve this?

Comment: there must be syntax error, or else it wont complaint.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181436/vsftpd-wont-start

Answer (score 15):

I had the same symptoms while trying to start vsftpd on an Ubuntu 16.04. In my case it was enough to comment out this line in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
listen_ipv6=YES
```

I don't know why i does not work with ipv6 for me, but I have no need for IP-v6 and disabling it solved the problem in my case.

Comment: Setting up C.H.I.P here. This did the trick!

Answer (score 8):

**step 1 : check the vsftpd.conf**

```
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

**Step 2 : To View which ftp service is running use**

```
$ lsof -i | grep ftp
```

**step 3 : To stop xinetd**

```
$ sudo service xinetd stop
```

**Step 4: After stoping xinetd restart your vsftpd service by typing**

```
$ /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

Comment: Replaced my vsftpd.conf file with contents of Step1 & the issue was resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In addition to some of the other solutions (`listen_ipv6=NO` and `listen=YES`), mine was failing with the same error because I had included comments after the things I had modified:

```
listen_ipv6=NO  # modified
```

That was also causing the same `status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT` error.
Could only figure it out by running the daemon directly:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf 
500 OOPS: bad bool value in config file for: listen_ipv6
```

Neither systemctl/service nor /var/log/vsftpd.log were any use.

Solution was to remove the trailing comment:

```
listen_ipv6=NO
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed by commenting out:

```
listen_ipv6=yes
```

and I am now active on vsftpd.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I even have SELinux disabled so that was not the cause and the config file for vsftpd is 100% perfect because `service vstfpd start` works instantly but it just would not start at startup.

My final solution was this bash script which runs with cron continually checking the service and works perfectly now and starts vsftp on startup by checking and seeing the service is dead and then starting it.

```
#!/bin/bash
service=vsftpd

if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
echo "$service is running!!!"
else
service vsftpd start
fi
```

And then my cron is

```
* * * * * sudo /usr/sbin/startvsftpd.sh
```

Comment: Looks like vsftpd service is not registered. Try with `systemctl enable vsftpd.service` or `service vsftpd.service enable` on `systemd` systems. Maybe `chkconfig vsftpd on` can work also.

Answer (score 0):

vsftpd needs the /etc/vsftpd.conf to be owned by root. Check who owns it with

```
ls -la /etc
```

To change the owner run the following command as as root or via sudo

```
chown root /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see /etc/vsftpd.conf. This file configuration　Listen=YES,If you setting,,You use vsftpd start serivce. You can try.
I have encountered this problem, I was so resolved, I hope you can help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)