# vsftp service failed

Tags: server, services, ftp, vsftpd

I'm new to ubuntu . I have to setup ftp server on ubuntu , vsftpd service always failing after basic installation and changes in /etc/vsftpd.conf file.

I've done below changes after install vsftpd software .

```
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=40100
```

I'm getting below error while checking the status of the service. Please help

```
root@helmor:~# sudo systemctl status vsftpd
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-06-04 19:13:59 IST; 22s ago
  Process: 1801 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 1798 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1801 (code=exited, status=2)
Jun 04 19:13:59 helmor systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP server...
Jun 04 19:13:59 helmor systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
Jun 04 19:13:59 helmor systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jun 04 19:13:59 helmor systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 04 19:13:59 helmor systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm using this guide http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Possibly related: [vsftpd-cannot read config file even when file exists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683413/vsftpd-cannot-read-config-file-even-when-file-exists)

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. Please try commenting out the below line in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
listen_ipv6=yes
```

Place a `#` at the start of this line so it looks like this

```
#listen_ipv6=yes
```

Save the file, then run

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
```

Hope this helps!

[image: vsftpd error image]